# Move data to next cell on click when repopulating a grid after update

Tags: c#, winforms, events, gridview

populate grid view and then on cell click i populate text box on cell click event like,

```
   private void dgvCompany_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = dgvCompany.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            ID = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtCompanyName.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtContactName.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtContactPersonPhone.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtCity.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            cbIsActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
        }
```

here ID is string variable after populating text box i edit and save update and then refill grid as previous method like,

```
public void FillCompanyInfo()
        {
            DataTable dtCompanyInfo = objFunctions.GetCompanyInfo();
            if(dtCompanyInfo.Rows.Count>0)
            {

                dgvCompany.DataSource = dtCompanyInfo;
                if (this.dgvCompany.Columns.Count == 8)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    checkColumn.Name = "";
                    checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
                    checkColumn.Width = 50;
                    checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                    checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values\\
                    dgvCompany.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
                }
            }
        }
```

here i use if condition counting column to 8 because each time it add column Select and after populating grid again when i click on grid and cell click event fire result in error ,

on line ,

```
 ID = dgvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

object reference not found because it is getting null on cell 0 while it was working fine before update on cell click and when i use break point i am getting ID on cells[1] and cell[0] is null

i am not understanding this error

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you call `FillCompanyInfo()` before Page.Load.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX Check if gridview has rows at all on CellClick. Also, what is the value of `i` when the error is thrown?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk here is `winforms`, not `ASP.NET`.

Comment: oops, sorry... Everything after the link is still applicable...

Comment: @Nikita it is showing same value of i as it gave before updating record that is index value

Comment: @SaluSala, What about row count?

Comment: @Nikita you are right i am calling on page load that is the error what it does when page load it repopulate grid and past the last check box column from last to first so it harm all column index value